# Semidecidability

Tags: logic

The set of satisfiable formulas (A formula is satisfiable if it is possible to find an interpretation (model) that makes the formula true) of FOL is a subset of the set of valid formulas (A formula is valid if all interpretations make the formula true). If that's the case then why doesn't the fact that the set of valid formulas of FOL is r.e (there exists a semidecidable procedure for enumerating them) entail that the sat of satisfiable formulas is r.e?

Is there a proof that the set of valid formulas of FOL is r.e that does not proceed via considering the completeness proof but, say, the recursiveness of the proof predicate?

Comment: valid $\mapsto$ [well-formed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_formula) $\:$ ? $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: A formula is valid if all interpretations make the formula true. A formula is satisfiable if it is possible to find an interpretation (model) that makes the formula true

Comment: In that case, what makes you think the "set of satisfiable formulas" $\hspace{2.34 in}$ "of FOL is a subset of the set of valid formulas"? $\;$

Comment: Take any formula A that is true on an interpretation I. To consider whether A is valid, this interpretation, I, amongst others, must be considered. In sum, if we have all the interpretations on which A comes out true, then we have an interpretation on which it comes out true (hence A being satisfiable).

Comment: Thus, "the set of valid formulas" "is a subset of the" "set of satisfiable formulas". $\:$ What makes you think the "set of satisfiable formulas" "of FOL is a subset of the set of valid formulas"? $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: No, I take what I said above to show that the set of satisfiable formulas of FOL is a subset of the set of valid formulas.

Comment: In that case, I don't understand what you mean by "we have all the interpretations on which A comes out true". $\:$ (I had thought you meant "we have that A comes out true in all interpretations".) $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: Yes, it seems to me that if I had written "we have/suppose that A comes out true in all interpretations", what I said is still correct.

Comment: "we have that A comes out true in all interpretations" if and only if A is valid, and "we have an interpretation on which it comes out true" if and only if A is satisfiable. $\:$ Thus, if you had written it that way then that sentence would correspond to "if A is valid then A is satisfiable". $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: I agree, but I think that the way I wrote it also implies "if A is valid then A is satisfiable". In any case, you now know what I mean.

Comment: The set of *valid* formulae is r.e.; it is proved that its complement (the set of "not valid") is not r.e.. This is the reason way the set of valid formulae is not recursive. The set of *contradictory* formulae (i.e. formulae always false) is r.e. (its is enough to "negate" the valid formuale) but its is proved that its compelment (i.e. the set of "not contradictory") is not r.e. (for the same reason above). The set of "not contradictory" formulae is exactly the set of *satisfiable* formulae.

Comment: Okay. $\:$ After showing, "if A is valid then A is satisfiable", you presumably generalize to "For all A, if A is valid then A is satisfiable.". $\:$ The previous sentence's last quote is equivalent to "the set of valid formulas" "is a subset of the" "set of satisfiable formulas", which makes me wonder how you take what you said in your "Take any formula ... being satisfiable)." comment "to show that the set of satisfiable formulas of FOL is a subset of the set of valid formulas." $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: Thanks Mauro.   Ricky, the whole point of my writing that if we have all the interpretations on which A comes out true, then we have an interpretation on which it comes out true (hence A being satisfiable) was to indicate that if a formula is valid then it is satisfiable. Punto e basta!

Comment: Well, I'd have accepted that with fewer comments if it actually led to the containment you were claiming. $\;\;\;$ $\:(\forall x)(\forall y)(x=y)\:$ is a satisfiable formula that is not valid; therefore the "set of satisfiable formulas" "of FOL is" **not** "a subset of the set of valid formulas". $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$

Answer (score 1):

*Long comment*

The set of *valid* formulae of *first-order* logic is *semi-decidable* (i.e. it is r.e.) because we can "enumerate" all the theorem of f-o logic with an effective procedure, generating mechanically all derivations of lenght 1, lenght 2, and so on.

By completeness, this enumeration will produce all valid formulae.

F-o logic in [undecidable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Completeness_and_undecidability), and thus the set of valid formulae is **not** recursive.

In order to apply you suggestion :

> Is there a proof that the set of valid formulas of FOL is r.e that does not proceed via considering the completeness proof but, say, the recursiveness of the proof predicate?

we have to define a recursive "proof predicate" $Prf_{FOL}(x,y)$ for FOL.

We can define the proof predicate through the [arithmetization of syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_incompleteness_theorems#Arithmetization_of_syntax) device in a suitable system $F$ with enough "resources".

See [Gödel's Incompleteness Theorems](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/goedel-incompleteness/) for the discussion about the requirement for a :

> consistent formal system $F$ within which a certain amount of arithmetic [...].

In the end, we have that the formula with Gödel number $n$ is a theorem of FOL iff $\exists x Prf_{FOL}(x,n)$ and this is more or less the same "procedure" above : generating in a "mechanical" way all the Gödel numbers of FOL's theorem, i.e. of *valid* FOL formulae.